# Two thread execute two method one is static and other is non static

Tags: java, multithreading

Two thread calls two different method , one is static and other is non-static but when i removed static from a method , i am getting different output than previous output which is same as when i put/remove static in/from both method than i am getting different output. Why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hello h = new Hello();
    AThread th1 = new AThread(h);
    BThread th2 = new BThread(h);
    th1.start();
    th2.start();
}
```

And there is tow different Thread class AThread & BThread which call method from Hello class.

```
public class AThread extends Thread {

    Hello h;

    public AThread(Hello h) {
        this.h = h;
    }

    public void run() {
        h.show();
    }
}

public class BThread extends Thread {

    Hello h;

    public AThread(Hello h) {
        this.h = h;
    }

    public void run() {
        h.display();
    }
}


public class Hello {

    static synchronized void show() {
        Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("SHOW\t:" + th.getName() + "\t" + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    static synchronized void display() {
        Thread th = Thread.currentThread();
        for (int i = 100; i < 110; i++) {
            System.out.println("Disp\t:" + th.getName() + "\t" + i + "\t");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:-
when i put static or when i removed static from both methods -

```
SHOW    :Thread-0   0
SHOW    :Thread-0   1
SHOW    :Thread-0   2
....
SHOW    :Thread-0   9
Disp    : Thread-1  100 
Disp    :Thread-1   101 
....
Disp    :Thread-1   109
```

when i put static in first method and  removed static from second method -

```
Disp    :Thread-1   100 
SHOW    :Thread-0   0
Disp    :Thread-1   101 
SHOW    :Thread-0   1
Disp    :Thread-1   102 
SHOW    :Thread-0   2
Disp    :Thread-1   103 
SHOW    :Thread-0   3
....
Disp    :Thread-1   109
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @guy  why i am getting different output .

Comment: I cannot see the code for `AThread` and `BThread`...

Comment: when i put static for only one method than both thread executes both method, but when  i remove static or i put static for both method than Thread-0 completes show() method than Thread-1 starts executing display() - can say that,  any one thread executes completely first than other thread starts executing

Comment: Why this question got -ve vote ? can you explain it before voting please otherwise remove -ve vote... i got blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke a `synchronized` method from a class, the thread that is doing the work locks the object. This way at any point only a single `synchronized` method will be invoked and other threads will wait for acquiring the object`s lock.

It is important to know that for a **non-static synchronized** methods the threads acquires the **lock of the actual instance of the object** (in your case - the Object **h**)

So when you use two non-static `synchronized` methods, they are syncrhzonized and the output is "SHOW" first and "DISP" second (or vice-versa).

**However, when you use a static synchronized method**, **the thread acquires the lock of the CLASS ITSELF** (in your case - **Hello** ).

So when you use two static synchronized methods, they are syncrhzonized and the output is "SHOW" first and "DISP" second (or vice-versa) AGAIN.

Last but not least - **when u use a non-static AND a static synchronized methods**, then the **first thread acquires the lock of the instance (h) and the second thread acquires the lock of the class (Hello)** - **these are two different locks** and this means the methods can be executed asynchronously by the two threads. That is why you receive a mixed result.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you didn't show us the code of your `AThread` and `BThread`. I assume that one thread calls `show()` and the others calls `display()`.

The reason why you are getting different behaviour when one method is static and the other is not, is because of what object is locked.

If method is non-static, synchronised method is equivalent to the following synchronized block: `synchronized (this) { /* ... */ }`.

If the method is static, synchronised method is equivalent to different synchronized block: `synchronized (Hello.class) { /* ... */ }`.

This means that if both methods are static or both methods are non-static, they share a single lock. However, if one method is static and the other is not, you have two different locks, so effectively you have no synchronization because every thread is using different lock.

Comment: why its maintaining thread order where both thread executing two different methods..

Comment: @sky Sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you mean by thread order?

Comment: when both methods is static or if both method is non-static than thread is executing like- Thread-0 is competing first till end the loop  than second Thread-1 start executing .

Comment: if only show() method is static than Thread-0 completes executing show() method and than Thread-1 starts executing display() method

Comment: @sky In first case (both the same), one thread acquires the lock and the other thread waits until the lock is released. In second case, both threads execute at the same time - the output is more or less random. I strongly recommend that you do some reading about concurrency before playing with it. Here is a good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: sir, both thread executing tow different method not same method, so i there should not be any lock to prevent executing other method by any other thread